# Is it okay to remove the if statement in MariaDB to extract the password_lifetime?

Tags: mariadb

I want to extract the password_lifetime in MariaDB.
In my opinion, there is no need to use the if statement.
Is it okay to only use IFNULL in this query?

(Original code)

```
  IF(
   IFNULL(JSON_EXTRACT(Priv, '$.password_lifetime'), -1) = -1,
   @@global.default_password_lifetime,
   JSON_EXTRACT(Priv, '$.password_lifetime')
  ) AS password_lifetime,
```

(Modified code)

```
IFNULL(JSON_EXTRACT(Priv, '$.password_lifetime'), 
@@global.default_password_lifetime
) AS password_lifetime,
```

The guideline from Maria DB is like below.
reference: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/user-password-expiry/

```
WITH password_expiration_info AS (
  SELECT User, Host,
  IF(
   IFNULL(JSON_EXTRACT(Priv, '$.password_lifetime'), -1) = -1,
   @@global.default_password_lifetime,
   JSON_EXTRACT(Priv, '$.password_lifetime')
  ) AS password_lifetime,
  JSON_EXTRACT(Priv, '$.password_last_changed') AS password_last_changed
  FROM mysql.global_priv
)
SELECT pei.User, pei.Host,
  pei.password_lifetime,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(pei.password_last_changed) AS password_last_changed_datetime,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(
   pei.password_last_changed +
   (pei.password_lifetime * 60 * 60 * 24)
  ) AS password_expiration_datetime
  FROM password_expiration_info pei
  WHERE pei.password_lifetime != 0
   AND pei.password_last_changed IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT pei.User, pei.Host,
  pei.password_lifetime,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(pei.password_last_changed) AS password_last_changed_datetime,
  0 AS password_expiration_datetime
  FROM password_expiration_info pei
  WHERE pei.password_lifetime = 0
   OR pei.password_last_changed IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would reduce it to, so that the column gets the right value

```
COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT(Priv, '$.password_lifetime'),@@global.default_password_lifetime) AS  password_lifetime
```

But you are right, the IF clause is superfluous.